# What is the connection between vector functions and space curves?

Tags: vectors, curves

I can't grasp what is the difference between vector functions and space carves. for example:
$$\gamma(t)=(f(t),g(t),h(t))$$
I can assume this as a vector that starts from $(0,0,0)$ and points to a specific coordinate and also as a curve. In many cases they are both same but some times it must be clarified. for example when we define $T(t)$ as the tangent vector, what is tangent on? curve or vector?

Comment: For a curve you might write  $$\gamma(t)=(f(t),g(t),h(t))$$        for $ 0\le t \le 1$. This will give the coordinates of a segment of your curve and the tangent vector lies along it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a somehow conventional abuse of terminology. Let's say you have a map
$$
\gamma:(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}^3
$$
usually with some extra properties such as differentiability. The *image* of $(0,1)$ under $\gamma$ is a "curve" in the space. Sometimes, people say that the map itself is the curve or a *parametrization* of the curve.

But there can be *other* map $\beta:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}^3$ that shares the same image of $\gamma$.

The tangent vector at point $\gamma(t_0)$ is given by $\gamma'(t_0)$.

Hope this helps!